# How to retrieve a specific field from an entity using Morphia and Play framework in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I have a big entity I created in Play! framework in Java and I would like to retrieve only a specific field from the database using Morphia and MongoDB. The entity itself is very big and contains many fields, so I would like to improve the performance of my application by retrieving only one field from it.

I know it is possible but I can't figure out exactly how to do it...
Here are some of the fields I have in my class `Shop`:

```
public String imagePath;
public String profileImagePath;
public String Motto;
@Reference
public Category primeCategory;
public boolean isOnline;
```

As you can see, the `primeCategory` field is a `Category` entity which I want to retrieve.
I saw something which suppose to achieve that in Morphia's website:

```
Datastore ds = null; 

Shop shop = ds.createQuery(Shop.class).retrievedFields(true, "primeCategory").get();
```

I'm not sure what exactly do I'm getting here.

It would be great if someone could explain to me if this is the way and how exactly I should do it, as well as provide an example.

Comment: I would definitely check out: Jongo as an ODM alternative. http://jongo.org/


and


https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo

just because there is not much active development on morphia atm.

Comment: What you're doing looks correct.  Is the `shop` object returned by the query null?  If not, is `shop.primeCategory` null?  Keep in mind that you're creating a query that will find all Shop objects but you're calling `get()` so you're only going to get back the first Shop object.

Comment: shop and shop.primeCategory aren't null. I just want to know if this is the way to do it or may be I'm missing something...

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
Shop.createQuery().retrievedFields(true, "primeCategory").get()
```

Comment: Well, the returned object (Shop) was null at all fields, and also the primeCategory. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Shop shop = ds.createQuery (Shop.class).retrievedFields (true,"primeCategory","Other_field_1","Other_field_2").get();
```

Would retrieve doc like this:

```
{
     "_id":ObjectId("..."),
     "primeCategory":{
                       ...
                     },
     "Other_field_1":"....",
     "Other_field_2":"...."

}
```

And you are having a good try.